# Eclipse class does not compiled in a particular workspace

Tags: java, eclipse

[image: error in eclipse]

[image]

I have the code above running in eclipse. It is a simple piece of code which should print "hello". When I run the code, I get the error code "error: Could not find or load main class testing.hello". Is that anything wrong with my eclipse? Is it I have to reinstall the software to use it? I can run the same piece of code in other laptop.

Comment: YOu should change the title of your question - eclipse troubleshooting is too general.

Comment: have tried restarting your ide... sometimes it solves my problem....

Comment: yup,but restarting my ide is not helping. It just doesn't work in that particular workspace. I create another workspace and everything is fine

Answer (score 0):

It seems your class is not compiled and hence eclipse is not able to find the class. You can try to do this thing:

1. Go to Project tab in Menu and click on 'Build Automatically'
2. Now edit your hello class. Editing will initiate the class to get compiled automatically.
3. Now try to Run the program

Hope it works!

Comment: @joy Try to clean your project. From menu Project->Clean

Answer (score 0):

your class does not seem to compile go to project menu tick build automatically check box and now edit your hello class and save it then try to run as java application